# on click enabled the disabled radio button rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two radio buttons in my rails app like below.

```
<td>
  <input checked="checked" onclick="make_disabled('<%=uniqid%>')"  type="radio" value='cash' name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][cash]" id="expense_cash<%=uniqid%>" >
</td>

<td>
  <input  onclick="make_enable('<%=uniqid%>')" type="radio" value='cheque' name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][cheque]" id="expense_cheque<%=uniqid%>" >
</td>
```

And three input fields like below:

```
<td>
  <input type="number" disabled='disabled' name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][bank_name]" id="expense_bank_name<%=uniqid%>" >
</td>

<td>
  <input type="text" disabled='disabled'  name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][comments]" id="expense_comments<%=uniqid%>" >
</td>

<td>
  <input type="text" disabled='disabled' name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][cheque_no]" id="expense_cheque_no<%=uniqid%%>" >
</td>
```

I have my `radio button` **cash** by default checked. And now on click of radio button **cheque** I want to enable the default disabled `input fields`.

Here's the JS script that I am trying to solve, but it is not working.

```
  function make_disabled(uniqid)
    {
     $("#collection_cheque_no"+uniqid).val('');
     $("#collection_cheque_no"+uniqid).attr('disabled','disabled');           
     $("#collection_bank_name"+uniqid).val('');
     $("#collection_bank_name"+uniqid).attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#collection_comments"+uniqid).val(''); 
     $("#collection_comments"+uniqid).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }

   function make_enable(uniqid)
    {
     $("#collection_chq_no"+uniqid).removeAttr('disabled');
     $("#collection_bank_name"+uniqid).removeAttr('disabled');
     $("#collection_comments"+uniqid).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: not working in what sense? `click` not happening? function never got called? check for console errors if any?

Comment: It is not behaving as a `radio`, I mean I am able to select both the `radio buttons`. 

And the function not getting called

Comment: You have to group your radios with same name?

Comment: both radio button name should be same, then only they behave as radio button,

Answer (score 1):

You have to group your radio with same name:

```
name="expense[<%=uniqid%>]"
```

And if you really require those extra brackets that you can serve with `data-*` attribute:

```
<input checked="checked" onclick="make_disabled('<%=uniqid%>')"  type="radio" value='cash' name="expense[<%=uniqid%>]" data-name="[cash]" id="expense_cash<%=uniqid%>" >
<input  onclick="make_enable('<%=uniqid%>')" type="radio" value='cheque' name="expense[<%=uniqid%>]" data-name="[cheque]" id="expense_cheque<%=uniqid%>" >
```

Comment: Well, I missed it but even when I have same name for them, It's not working.

`<td>
      <input checked="checked" onclick="make_disabled('<%=uniqid%>')"  type="radio" value='cash' name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][cheque]" id="expense_cash<%=uniqid%>" >
</td>


<td>
      <input  onclick="make_enable('<%=uniqid%>')" type="radio" value='cheque' name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][cheque]" id="expense_cheque<%=uniqid%>" >
</td>`

Comment: @Suraj can you post the generated html instead?